# Angular http interceptor response function removes message param from server response

Tags: angularjs, response, angular-http-interceptors

In my application all server responses are as follows:

```
response = {
    data: {},
    status: STATUS_CODE,
    message: STRING_MESSAGE
}
```

I want to use angular's http response function to display a response message for some of my webservices in a toast component. In the interceptor I have a simple response function:

```
response = function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

which logs a response object:

```
{
    data:{}, // object response.data
    config: {},
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: function()
}
```

There is no message parameter that server sends. Does it mean that interceptor erase some part of my servers response? One of the solutions would be to overwrite a statusText value. I tried to modify server response like

```
response = {
        data: {},
        status: STATUS_CODE,
        statusText: STRING_MESSAGE
    }
```

but it didn't work, I still had statusText: 'OK' and still no message param in interceptor's response object

Comment: the server response is in `data` property. That should not be empty object or something is wrong in actual request

Comment: The interceptor's response.data is not empty and is the same as server's response.data, so has no status and no message attribute.

Comment: then inspect the actual request in dev tools network and see exactly what is sent. Also a demo in plunker showing this would help. perhaps you forgot to return something in the interceptor? not enough context shown and it's a bit confusing as shown

Answer (score 0):

Check data property in your interceptor response. It might be like this

```
{
   data:{     
      data: {},
      status: STATUS_CODE,
      message: STRING_MESSAGE
   }, // object response.data
   config: {},
   status: 200,
   statusText: 'OK',
   headers: function()
}
```